# UITableViewCell　の　viewWithTag　の挙動がおかしい

Tags: ios, swift

storyboard　上に設定しておいたセルを

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath);
```

にてセルを取得し、

```
if let image = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView
```

にて　storyboard　で設定した　セル内のビューにアクセスしています。
ですが　viewWithTag　の挙動がおかしく、
行のビューによって　nil　になります。
（行単位で　nil　になるのではなく、　その行の他のビューは正常なのに一部だめだったり）

解決策分かる方お願いします。

行１
tag1:ok
tag2:ok
tag3:ok
tag4:ok

行２
tag1:ng
tag2:ok
tag3:ok
tag4:ok

行３
tag1:ok
tag2:ng
tag3:ok
tag4:ok

行４
tag1:ok
tag2:ok
tag3:ok
tag4:ok

【セルの使い回し状況】
↑このテスト時は画面内に表示されるビューは見えているのは３〜４

Answer (score 0, accepted):

凡ミスでした
セルを取得するときにセルのコンテンツビューに対して　tag　をセットしていたのですが、
そのセットした値が　コンテンツ内のSBで設定した　tab　と重複したのが原因でした。